# server client socket data transmission

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to understand when data from server reach client and vice versa.

Let's assume that we have server which binds tcp/ip socket at some port of machine #1.

Let's assume that we have client which locates at machine #2 and is successfully connected tcp/ip socket to same port of machine #1.

When server is writing data to socket, but client is not yet started reading, where will data be stored?

Will data be stored in internal buffer of network layer/socket of machine #1, waiting for client. When client start reading data, network layer will get notification and transmit data?

Or data will be automatically transmitted to internal buffer of network layer/socket of machine #2 and wait there? And when application will start reading it, data is already there?

Do we have a mechanism to choose which flow we would prefer?

Comment: OSes do not implement the OSI sever-layer model. The IP Services model is closer to what is used in the real world, but remember that models are just models, and there is nothing requiring anything to use any model. There are protocols in use that do not actually fit into a model.

Comment: @RonMaupin actually the model is not important in the question. I'd like to understand, would data be transmitted to client machine, waiting for read, or it will wait at server's machine, waiting for read request.

Comment: So remove it from your question. Sockets have a send buffer and a receive buffer. In this case the relevant buffers are the send buffer at the sender and the receive buffer at the receiver.

Comment: @user207421 removed. In which of those buffers will be stored message when server sent it, but client didn't read it?

Comment: If it has been transmitted to the receiver and the receiver has ACKd it, it is in the receiver's receive buffer, otherwise still in the sender's send buffer.

Comment: But how can I know will it be transmitted to the receiver or not?
Do we have a mechanism to choose which flow I want?

Comment: That was actually my question. If you can write it as answer, I would accept.
Answering your question: I'm trying to create regression test for a process, and it would be easier to determine is it working well or not, if I would have understanding or control over sockets data transmitting.

Comment: Reposting that you can't know that. TCP ACKs are not visible to the application in any way. And it wouldn't make any difference to your applicaton if you could tell which buffer it was in.

Comment: It would be appreciated if moderators could cease deleting valid content here. Hard to see the point of the site otherwise.